# $\sum_{n=N}^{\infty} a_{n}$ is convergent $\implies$ $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_{n}$ is convergent? $a_n\leq b_n$ imply $\sum a_{n}\leq\sum b_{n}$?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

I have two questions regarding infinite series that I think makes intuitive sense, but I couldn't find in my textbook (and on google - I guess it must be out there, but I probably used the wrong keywords).

1. Is it true that if $\sum_{n=N}^{\infty} a_{n}$ is convergent $\implies$ $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_{n}$ is convergent (Provided that $a_n$ is defined for $n<N).$
2. The comparison test tells me: 
   Suppose that we have two series $\sum a_{n}$ and $\sum b_{n}$ with $a_{n}, b_{n} \geq 0$ for all $n$ and $a_{n} \leq b_{n}$ for all $n .$ Then,

- If $\sum b_{n}$ is convergent then so is $\sum a_{n}$.
- If $\sum a_{n}$ is divergent then so is $\sum b_{n}$

   *But is it also true that: $\sum a_{n}\leq\sum b_{n}$?*

---

I think it would make sense, since $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_{n}=\sum_{n=0}^{N-1} a_{n}+ \sum_{n=N}^{\infty} a_{n}$. And the first sum is always finite. So the series should be convergent iff the second sum converges?

 
 It would also make sense if $a_n\leq b_n$ then $\sum a_{n} \leq \sum b_{n}$

Comment: 1.- Perfect.

2.- Try to prove it using the sequence of partial sums and properties of limits